# What is the equivalent of Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, windows-10-universal, .net-core

In .net framework we could get the starting assembly using:

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
```

But that is removed from .NET Core. Also there is no AppDomain. How can I get access to the entry assembly in .NET Core and Windows Universal applications?

(I need to find all of its embedded resource keys)

Comment: try Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()

Comment: That doesn't exist either. Those static methods are removed from Assembly class in .NET core!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` is available in *.NET Standard 1.5*, but not in versions 1.0 through 1.4. If you are only developing .NET Core and *Universal Windows* applications, version 1.5 should be sufficient for your needs.

If I remember correctly, `AppDomain` is destined to appear in *.NET Standard 2.0*. It is not available now.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But my library is shared between Xamarin for iOS and Android too which use Mono.

Comment: As far as I know, Xamarin iOS and Android should also be able to use *.NET Standard 1.5* assemblies.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up injecting the entry assembly into the library.

**In the library:**

```
class AssemblyHelper 
{
     // This can be called instead of Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()
     public static Func<Assembly> GetEntryAssembly;
}
```

In the start-up application (which uses the library):

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        AssemblyHelper.GetEntryAssembly = () => typeof(Program).GetAssembly();

        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work in a library that knows nothing about `Program`.

Comment: True. But you can provide this way of injecting the assembly and add "setup documentation" for the users of your library to add the code above to their own Program. Not ideal, but doable.

Comment: This doesn't even try to answer the question. Altough it might be what you did to solve _your_ problem, it's not very helpful for people coming here and expecting to find a solution. Anders answer is much better.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I marked his reply as the correct answer.

Comment: Answer helped me though on a legacy project, so +1