# Get Executing Assembly Name in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

I have a legacy class library targeting netstandard1.2 where we need to get the assembly name where this library is referenced.

Using the following give us the name of class library and it works fine.

```
typeof(MyHelperClass).GetTypeInfo().Assembly
```

but we need to get the referenced assembly name. Following code will work fine for standard .net but not for **.net core**

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name;
```

Is there a way to get the executing assembly name using .net core while targeting .net standard 1.2?

Comment: Strongly related: [What is the equivalent of Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() in .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40483189/)

Comment: Do you mean executing assembly or entry assembly?

Comment: var assembly = GetType().Assembly.FullName; ??

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen executing or entry, either will work in our use case.

Comment: @Joshit This didn't worked since it gives the assemebly name of my own application, not where it has been referenced and consumed by user application

Comment: But what Joshit is talking about will find the ___currently executing___ assembly. His `GetType()` will get the run-time type of `this` (so if the class has been inherited in another assembly and we are of that type, we will get that other assembly). Based on [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/dotnet/api/system.type.assembly?view=netstandard-2.0) I think you need `GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name` with your version of .NET Standard.

Answer (score 15):

If it is above .NetCore 1.5 you can either use the following:

```cs
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
```

or (depending on your usecase):

```cs
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
```

Don't forget to import the library:

```cs
using System.Reflection;
```

Comment: I get the name of the the library using both Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Name and Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name where I need the root application that called the library...

Comment: @JasonDWilson, try Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(); That worked for me.